# android long press to show menu with delete action

Tags: android

i have an android app with a custom list view. i get the data of my local sql database. now i would like add a function, to delete any items of my list view / database.

i would like to realize a long press on any row and show a menu like this where i can chose the delete option:

[image]

but i don't know how, because this is the first time, that i would like to do this :/

Comment: There are a lot of examples for this on the web, just search of *Android popup menu*, here is one example: http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example (and of course, use *LongClickListener*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use context menus
see 'http://www.javatpoint.com/android-context-menu-example' for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can `setOnItemLongClickListener()` to the listview and show, a options dialog, and on clicking delete button delete that row.

Comment: add some example that will help more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Try this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){ 
                   @Override 
                   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) 
                  { 
                    //Your code to show the menu
                  } 
             });
```